# "aapt.exe" exited with code 1. in VS 2015

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

"aapt.exe" exited with code 1.
Getting this eoor while running a Xamarin android  application in visual studio 2015 ;can anyone give the solution for the issue arised.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the symbol - in any of the filenames of your solution (anywhere) thats it!!! got it just now.